# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with negative speed

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

An Orsntein-Uhlenbeck (OU) process $U$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is usually defined as solving the following SDE:
\begin{align}
\text{d}U_t&=\kappa(\mu-U_t)\text{d}t+\sigma\text{d}W_t, \quad\forall t>0
\\[3pt]
U_0&=u\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
for some Brownian motion $W$ and parameters $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\kappa,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.

**Can we still define the OU process for the case $\kappa<0$?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wlog consider $\mu = 0$. If $\kappa< 0$ we can rewrite $\kappa=-\beta,\,\beta >0$. We get $dU_t=\beta U_t dt+\sigma dW_t$. Now if we solve the SDE:
$$\begin{aligned}dU_t-\beta U_t dt&=\sigma dW_t\\
d(U_t e^{-\beta t})&=\sigma e^{-\beta t}dW_t\\
\implies U_t&=ue^{\beta t}+\sigma \int_0^te^{\beta(t-s)}dW_s
\end{aligned}$$
We see that $U_t \sim \mathcal{N}(u e^{\beta t},\sigma^2(e^{2\beta t}-1)/(2\beta))$ so that $|E[U_t]|\to \infty$ (if $u\neq 0$), $V[U_t]\to \infty$ so it cannot be Ornstein-Uhlenbeck.

Comment: Thank you @Snoop. Two follow-up questions, first why does the divergence of expectation/variance over $t$ imply that the process is not an OU? Secondly, even though the process is not OU, is it still a well-defined process with a solution? I reckon it is well defined, usual Lipschitz-continuity conditions apply to $h(t,x)\equiv\kappa(\mu-x)$ and $g(t,x)\equiv\sigma$.

Comment: @MorrisFletcher (1) if a process is OU it has finite limits for $E[U_t],V[U_t]$ so since these diverge in this case, we haven't obtained a OU process as the solution; (2) yes, the solution is the process above, which is simply not OU.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications @Snoop. I guess my main point was really whether the process is well-defined (which you confirmed), even though I did not see any existence problem when $\kappa<0$ $-$ but I always saw OU processes defined for the case $\kappa>0$. I guess the reason is simply that when $\kappa<0$ then the process is no longer mean-reverting and expectation/variance diverge, thus why we generally circumscribe to the case where speed is positive.